# Getting stripe gateway to accept a variable as a amount for charge

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Hi I have a variable called $total which is set from a hidden field in a form on another page

```
$total = $_POST['myHiddenValue'];
```

In Stripe I'm attempting to use this variable as an amount parameter

```
  Stripe_Charge::create(array(
                            "amount" => $total,
                            "currency" => "gbp",
                            "card" => $_POST['stripeToken']));
```

this throws an error of 'missing amount param'

if I set $total before hand as:

```
$total = 5000;
```

it works but I don't want to hard code in a amount.

using below doesn't work either, it throws and 'Invalid positive integer' error

"amount" => (int)$total,

Does anyone know Stripe well to offer me some help.

thanks

Comment: What is the value of `$total`?

Answer (score 1):

'amount' is in cents and should be an integer and not a decimal.

$Total = '50.43';

'amount' => $Total*100,